# My cat won't stop urinating in one area

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training

This is a question for a friend.

They have a cat that uses the liter box normally for #2, but chooses to urinate in one specific area of the carpet. The issue has gotten bad enough that the area has browned. They have tried several cleaning solutions to remove the odor, but the cat still appears to target the same area.

I have read several other posts involving urinating around the house, and we will try the solutions listed [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/how-can-stop-my-adult-cat-from-urinating-in-inappropriate-places), notably:

- Trying a different box
- Trying different litter
- Bringing the cat to a vet if necessary

Is there any reason **for this specific behavior** (notably different than the question linked), and is there any way we can properly clean the carpet?

Comment: What kind of cleaning solutions have you tried? Cat urine is incredibly hard to get rid of, and even if you can't smell it, chances are your cat can (especially if the area is discolored). I think there might be a couple variations, but [there's a question about getting the smell out of a mattress](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/how-can-i-get-old-cat-urine-smell-out-of-a-mattress) that might help.

Answer (score 3):

Your question identifies that the cat will "urinate in one specific area of the carpet".  This is a an issue that we see sometimes in rabbits, they decide "this is the place!"

The solution with rabbits is to put the litter box where "they want it to be".  Occasionally people are able to slowly (over days or weeks) to move the litter box to where they person prefers it to be, and the pet adapts.  But first put the litter box where they want it, and leave it there for a few days. It is also possible that the litter box will need to stay where "they want it to be".

If the area is a bit bigger than the litter box you can use the [solution here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1185/cats-making-a-mess-with-litter/1187#1187) to cover a wider area.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put some food on a paper plate, on the spot of carpet that the cat has been peeing on. Then leave the paper plate there for a couple of weeks. This will cause the cat to associate that spot with eating, rather than urination. Cats do not like to urinate near where they eat.

I read this tip a long time ago; I have not personally tried it but it seems logical.