# How can I stop my dog from peeing on our neighbor's door?

Tags: dogs, training

My dog in general is well behaved and only pees outdoors... Except in one case where the dog will pee if another dog had once peed there.

Because of this, about once every two months, when we go out to walk, my dog will pee on my neighbors door inside out appartment complex because long ago a dog came in and peed there. (Turns out the friend of someone else in the building brings another dog in once every two months....)  And yes, my dog is leashed, and I keep the leash as short as possible while going up the stairs.

The hallway and door are tiled . How can I get rid of the scent or retrain the dog that this spot is not allowed to be peed on?

Below is a picture of the door being peed on. Its on the top right of the stairs.

I read on one website that if I put food or dog treats on the spot, it will prevent the dog from peeing there because dogs won't mark where their food is? Would that actually work? How could I implement that in this situation?

[image: The door that gets peed on]

Comment: Keep the dog on leash and away from the door. If you can't change the dog's mind, prevent the problem from arising.

Comment: The hallway is not wide enough to keep him from the door.  The area is all tile.

Comment: Seems the issue is with the other dog owner letting their dog pee inside the building in the forst place...

Comment: @Aravona Agreed, but I have to deal with it somehow and stop the cycle.

Comment: @avi the thing that jumped to mind first was just clean the door with an enzyme based pee remover... But cleaning someone elses door is a sort of Monica from Friends level of weird

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean it, they sell cleaners meant to rid a peed on spot of all scent so as not to trigger another occurrence through instinct. You can probably find them in most pet stores and some supermarkets.

I wouldn't bother though. I don't think he can smell the spot from the side walk. I think it's a behavior and he thinks its about time to remark. The solution is pretty simple from my point of view. You dog needs to be on a leash until he comes when called every time.

I'm sure you feel like your dog is well trained and that this might be the only exception, but the truth is that if he doesn't come everytime you call him, he's not trained well enough to be off leash.

That's not something I'm just throwing out there. I have a jack Russell and it took almost two years before I could fully trust her off leash. Even when she listened well to me, she could still focus in on a squirrel, rabbit, etc... and I just don't think she could hear me in that focused state of mind. It took a long time. I had to run her down several times. I finally got her to where I'd trust her recall in almost any situation, but I still put a leash on if I feel like it's appropriate, like when I go to the vet.

So just leash your dog, give him the opportunity to misbehave and correct it when it happens. In the mean time, start working on his recall and give him a reason to return. Many people have an emergency recall, where the dogs gets an awesome treat, like a hot dog. I saw a person one time who had a freeze command, which I wish my dog knew. I've been in a situation before where a road was between me and the dog. A car was coming and most peoples safety rope is being able to a call the dog to them. However, doing this would have pulled her out into danger. If I could have told her to "freeze" she would have been much safer.

Comment: There is no sidewalk. It's an appartment building and the door touches the stairs that we take to get to the street. There is no space to avoid the area. Everything is indoors.

Comment: I've added a picture to the question.

Comment: If you put a leash on him and don't let him stop to pee, I'm not sure how he's peeing on it. Maybe if you kept your body between him and the door, kept your leash short, and just kept him moving, he wouldn't be able to pee on it. It just sounded before like you had him outside and he was running up in a neighbors yard is why I answered in that way. The descenting cleaner might help in that situation.

Comment: The last time I tried to pull him away, he left a splash/trail.  I have not tried body blocking him, though I fear getting peed on.

Comment: @avi going to sound gross, but wear some old pants next time you go for a walk and try it anyway. Honestly, getting peed on (while gross) isn't the end of the world, and it might work.

Comment: @Zaralynda that's an interetsting idea, but I don't know how practical that would be.  Remember, this has only happened once every 2 months or so, since the first time the other dog peed there. (Maybe even less frequently)

Comment: I really don't think your dog will pee on you. They do know right from wrong. He just thinks that peeing on a door that has already been marked is right. Instinctually, he's completely correct in what he's doing, we just have to show him that's not how your pack behaves, the same as when you don't let him jump on you with muddy paws, or at all hopefully. You need to keep the leash short, though no tension on it, keep his head/shoulder by your outside leg, and keep moving. If he goes toward the door, then give a slight tug of the leash to readjust him.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with keeping the dog on a leash. Since you already know what's coming when you reach near your neighbor's door, you should steer your dog away from where he likes to pee.

Answer (score 0):

100% effective prevention should be obtainable by putting a diaper on your dog before walking past the area.  There are multiple source for 'dog diapers' in pet supply stores and online.

This related question may also offer insight [How can I eliminate set-in dog urine scent from a carpet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2571) on cleaning.